# How to set Desktop to show files and folders from different directory?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, desktop, google-drive

I recently installed the Google Drive app onto my main PC which creates a Drive folder that syncs the files I have on Drive with the files in the Drive folder. Is there anyway to set up Windows 8 so the files and folders in my synced Drive folder appear on my Desktop?

Comment: Would a shortcut to said folder not be sufficient for this?

Answer (score 1):

The built in Windows Feature is:
[Include folders in a library](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/include-folders-in-a-library)

and in Vista or later:

```
mklink /J Destination Source
```

to create a [NTFS junction Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).

There is also an external tool:
[Windows Sysinternals Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx).

Comment: I can confirm the NTFS Junction Point method works on my Windows machine as of 2023, which is 9 years later.

Answer (score 0):

In most Windows Operating Systems you can create shortcuts on the desktop to folders that you require these are then automatically synchronised with each other, You can either:

1. Navigate to the file/folder (its current location) you wish to appear on your desktop
2. Right click the file/folder
3. Select create shortcut, this will create a replica of the file/folder in the current directory
4. Drag and drop the created replica to the desktop

or on the desktop itself:

1. Right click and select New
2. Select Shortcut
3. in the bar that appears in a window you can browse to the file you wish to shortcut to and select it.
4. once the file/folder is selected, its file path wile appear in the bar.
5. Click Next and the wizard will ask for you to name the shortcut file, you can name it anything you want and then click finish.